# How to change the Android Bluetooth name in code?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Now I am using BluetoothAdapter.setName("newName").
However it seems not work...
I use another Android Device to scanning the bluetooth that is renamed in code, but it is not changed...

How can I change the bluetooth device name and other device can see such change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that bluetooth state is ON before changing the name. Are you doing that?

Here is the documentation for `setName` in android developer docs.

> Set the friendly Bluetooth name of the local Bluetooth adapter.
>
> This name is visible to remote Bluetooth devices.
>
> Valid Bluetooth names are a maximum of 248 bytes using UTF-8 encoding,
> although many remote devices can only display the first 40 characters,
> and some may be limited to just 20.
>
> If Bluetooth state is not STATE_ON, this API will return false. After
> turning on Bluetooth, wait for ACTION_STATE_CHANGED with STATE_ON to
> get the updated value.
>
> Requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
>
> Parameters name   a valid Bluetooth name Returns true if the name was
> set, false otherwise

Comment: please mention what was the problem in your case.

Comment: me too... my bluetooth device even not shown (detected) in the other device when I changed its name. @maveroid